# jQuery UI Widget Override Method

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I am trying to write a widget that allows the user of my code to override an event.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtAdV/2/) of what I am trying to do.

Code:

`<div>Place Holder</div>​`

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("ui.mywidget", {
        options: {

        },
        _create: function () {

        },
        myevent: function () {
            alert('test1');
        }
    });

    $('#placeHolder').mywidget({
        myevent: function () {
            alert('test2');
        }            
    });

    $('#placeHolder').mywidget('myevent');

})(jQuery);​
```

`$('#placeHolder').mywidget('myevent');` results in an alert that says "test1" but it should say "test2".  I thought it would just be this simple.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I assume the widget does other things too, otherwise people could just set the `click()` handler themselves...?

Comment: "click" should be an option that accepts a function if you want developers to be able to easily override it for a single instance, though I think this is not very intuitive, wouldn't it be easier for them to just bind to the click event and add their own callback?

Comment: You are both right but I am still unable to allow a method to be overridden by passing it as an option.  I changed my example to be less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite old question but someone else may have the same one.

As said in comment, you could define a default event handler function as an option that can be easily overriden:

```
$.widget("ui.mywidget", {

    // Default option
    options: {
        'myevent': function() {
            alert('test1');
        }
    },

    // Public 'myevent' function
    myevent: function() {
        if($.isFunction(this.options.myevent))
            this.options.myevent();
    }
});

// Override the default 'myevent' option
$('#placeHolder').mywidget({
    myevent: function() {
        alert('test2');
    }            
});

$('#placeHolder').mywidget('myevent');
```

I updated your <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtAdV/4/)</kbd> to illustrate it.